# Retrieving selected files from a directory?

Tags: c#

I have a C# windows program in which I need have a control that acts like Windows Explorer. I'm new to C# and haven't seen any kind of controls that can accomodate this functionality. Are there any controls similar to this that I can use? If not, what would be the best approach for this type of functionality?

Thanks

Comment: [OpenFileDialog Class](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.openfiledialog(v=vs.110).aspx) or the OpenFileDialog Control (in your ToolBox). Knowing what Project template you're using would also help your case.

Comment: What type of project are you using?  VS has Dialog class which is different depending on project type.

Comment: What specifically does *act like Windows Explorer* mean? This question is far too vague.

Answer (score 0):

Take a look at the OpenFileDialog control. You can drag and drop this on your form in the designer.  Just set the Multiselect property to true to allow multiple file selection. It also has an InitialDirectory property.

https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.openfiledialog(v=vs.110).aspx

```
    if (openFileDialog1.ShowDialog() == DialogResult.OK)
        {
            List<string> files = new List<string>();
            foreach (string file in openFileDialog1.FileNames)
            {
                files.Add(file);
            }
            MessageBox.Show("There were: " + files.Count +
                " files selected.");

        }
```